# Run local commands with Fabric

Tags: python, build, local, fabric, yarnpkg

My environments are based on windows with vagrant or docker as the actual environments. I'd like to set up a quick way of ad hoc deploying stuff directly from windows though, it would be great if I could just run

```
fab deploySomething
```

And that would for example locally build an react app, commit and push to the server. However I'm stuck at the local bit.

My setup is:
Windows 10
Fabric 2
Python 3

I've got a fabfile.py set up with a simple test:

```
from fabric import Connection, task, Config

@task
def deployApp(context):
    config = Config(overrides={'user': 'XXX', 'connect_kwargs': {'password': 'YYY'}})
    c = Connection('123.123.123.123', config=config)
    # c.local('echo ---------- test from local')             
    with c.cd('../../app/some-app'):
        c.local('dir') #this is correct
        c.local('yarn install', echo=True)
```

But I'm just getting:

```
'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

you can replace 'yarn' with pretty much anything, I can't run a command with local that works fine manually. With debugging on, all i get is:

```
DEBUG:invoke:Received a possibly-skippable exception: <UnexpectedExit: cmd='cd ../../app/some-app && yarn install' exited=1>
```

which isn't very helpful...anyone came across this? Any examples of local commands with fabric I can find seem to refer to the old 1.X versions

Comment: What the OS of the server you are trying to connect to? 
Why do you use this path `../../app/some-app`? I would assume when you connect to the server, you can use the absolute path instead of the relative path! have you tried that?

Comment: this command refers to the LOCAL instance on windows, mac or a linux vagrant box. the command c.local('dir') works fine, it shows the relevant output on windows, it also works with c.local('ls') on mac or linux. But I can't run any other commands, like node --version or yarn install as per the example...

Answer (score 4):

To run local commands, run them off of your `context` and not your connection.  n.b., this drops you to the `invoke` level:

```
from fabric import task

@task
def hello(context):
    with context.cd('/path/to/local_dir'):
        context.run('ls -la')
```

That said, the issue is probably that you need the fully qualified path to `yarn` since your environment's path hasn't been sourced.